# Delete parent and child records without using on delete cascade

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, parent-child, parent

So, let's we go to the point. I have a project that where the user can delete the records from the database, but of course if I delete the parent record, I will get an error because it has child records in another table. So, what I want to do is I want to delete the parent records, and when I delete it, all the rows in child records that include the parents key or primary key will be deleted as well without using cascade.

Here is the code for example :

```
if (row != -1)
        {
            tbl_employee.Rows.RemoveAt(row);

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(txt_employeeid.Text.ToString());
            employee emp = db.employees.Single(x => x.employeeid == id);
            db.employees.DeleteOnSubmit(emp);
db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click the row first!");

        }
```

But, I have an error `The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint`. I know I can use `on delete cascade`, but is there any other thing for delete the child records without using it?

Comment: Is the problem that you can't delete the parent without deleting the children first? Just delete the children and THEN delete the parent. Do you not know what referencing tables may be involved?

Comment: Yes! But of course I can't delete the children first, how if the user want to delete the parent without knowing anything about the children? So, what I want to do is when the user delete the parent records, the children records will be deleted as well. And for the referencing, let's say the employee id, the one that will be deleted is in employee table and production table.

Comment: You can do this with an instead of trigger if you dont want to do it in your client

Comment: Did you consider what you'll lose by hard deleting all of the data? Would a soft delete be a better option, i.e. having an `IsDeleted` column of something similar that you set to `true` when they delete. You'd need to add logic to filter out deleted records, but referential integrity would be maintained. Otherwise, why can't you delete the child records first as you would have the parent id to delete the child rows with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Cascade Delete` would be the simplest, but I agree its not a good solution since you have no control over which child tables may be deleted and which may not.

So you have 2 options left :

1. Delete the rows in the child tables in your client before deleting the master (in the same transaction off course)
2. Delete the rows in the child tables (and the master table row) in an `instead of trigger`

The latter has the advantage that it is done on the database side again, and like the other solutions also gives you control which tables may be deleted and which do not.
You can even put some extra checks in there if you like.

Comment: `The latter has the advantage that it is done on the database side again, and give you control which tables may be deleted and which do not` CASCADEs also give precise control of which tables get deleted on each action, in the form of the FOREIGN KEY definition. And generally triggers are an inferior choice if a native DB feature does the job. Client-side is an option if using the DB is not possible, but personally I would just stay with the cascade.

Comment: @Alejandro From the question of the OP i assumed he did not want to use `cascade delete` So I just summed up his options and in this case the `instead of trigger`seemed the only remaining option to keep it on the database side. I use them myself in some situations and unless you are deleting several 100 records at once the performance issue is not noticed here

Comment: @Alejandro I altered the text in my question to `and like the other solutions also gives you control...` Does this makes is more clear ?